# Подключение стилей и скриптов в плагинах Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Начал изучать тему подключений плагинов в Wordpress, но столкнулся с проблемой (вначале все работало): перестали подключаться js-скрипты и стилевые файлы.
Собственно, весь функциональный (запускной файл плагина).

```
<?php
/*
*@package Sergalas
*@version 1.0
*/
/*
Plugin Name: The Fraction Slider Plugin
Description: Мой первый плагин WordPress. 
Version: 0.1
Author: Sergalas

*/

function true_plugin_init() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fractionsliderstyle', plugins_url('/css/fractionslider.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fractionsliderresetstyle', plugins_url('/css/reset.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fractionsliderstylethesomeplugin', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fractionsliderpuginstyle', plugins_url('/css/plugin-style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('fractionslidercode', plugins_url('/js/jquery.fractionslider.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('fractionslidermain', plugins_url('/js/main.js', __FILE__), array('fractionslidercode'));
    wp_enqueue_script('optioncode', plugins_url('/js/option.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_plugin_init');
```

для любителей решать вопрос через wp_register_style(''),wp_enqueue_style('') отвечу сразу я так вопрос уже пытался решить собственно вот так

```
<?php
/*
*@package Sergalas
*@version 1.0
*/
/*
Plugin Name: The Fraction Slider Plugin
Description: Мой первый плагин WordPress. 
Version: 0.1
Author: Sergalas

*/

function true_plugin_init() {
    wp_register_style('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_register_style('fractionslidercode', plugins_url('/js/jquery.fractionslider.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_register_style('fractionslidermain', plugins_url('/js/main.js', __FILE__), array('fractionslidercode'));
    wp_register_style('optioncode', plugins_url('/js/option.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('fractionslidercode');
    wp_enqueue_script('fractionslidermain');
    wp_enqueue_script('optioncode');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_plugin_init');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос сам. Все, как в басне Крылова: ларчик просто открывался. Надо было `add_action( 'admin_init', 'true_plugin_init');` вот так написать.